# Need to preview zip file as google. I tried to read file using zipjs

Tags: jquery

I tried to preview a zip file in jquery. I am able to read all the file path using zip-js but I am not able to preview like google. I need the following image style preview.

[image: Preview image 1]

[image: Preview image 2]

```
 <pre>

      {
  "zip.js-master": [
    ".project",
    "README",
    {
     "WebContent": [
        ".jshintrc",
        "deflate.js",
        "inflate.js",
        "mime-types.js",
        {
          "pako": [
            "codecs.js"
          ]
        },
        {
          "tests": [
            "arraybuffer.js",
            "base64.js",
            "config.js",
            "dataview.js",
            "lorem.txt",
            "lorem.zip",
            "lorem2.zip",
            "lorem_store.zip",
             "test1.html",
            "test1.js",
            "test10.html",

          ]
        },
        "z-worker.js",
        "zip-ext.js",
        "zip-fs.js",
        "zip.js",
        {
          "zlib-asm": [
            "codecs.js"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
 </pre>
```

Comment: Please provide some code and explain what exactly you have tried so far.

Comment: Please check the code above. I tried to convert the following code in an preview image format. Kindly check the   Preview image 1 Preview image 2

Comment: Are you saying you were able to extract the data you need from the zipfile, but now want someone to design the layout for you?

Comment: I don't know how to get the webContent on click webcontent folder. I need to display only the current folders data not subfolders

Comment: Just now, I completed this concept. Thank you for everyone who tried to help me.

Comment: @Thiru can you tell future readers how you did it??

Answer (score 0):

Try JSZip,it is a javascript library for creating, reading and editing .zip files

https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/reading-zip-files-in-javascript-using-jszip/